# How/Why does parameter binding work without @RequestParam?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, request, spring-restcontroller

I have an endpoint declared like this

```java
@GetMapping("/shoebox")
public ResponseEntity<?> find(ShoeBox shoebox) {
    ...
}
```

When I make a request like `/shoebox?color=blue&size=small`

It correctly binds `color` and `size` to a new `ShoeBox` object.

But if I delcare with `@RequestParam` like this

```java
@GetMapping("/shoebox")
public ResponseEntity<?> find(@RequestParam ShoeBox shoebox) {
    ...
}
```

Then I get this error

```json
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Required request parameter 'shoebox' for method parameter type ShoeBoxis not present",
    "timestamp": 1621373682288,
    "errors": [
        "MissingServletRequestParameterException"
    ]
}
```

I understand a little of why it doesn't work with `@RequestParam` because I'm not using a single param, but what I don't understand is why it works without any annotation at all. How does it know to bind it? Is this functionality documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is in charge of solving if you do not place any annotation on parameters?

It is this [RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.html) the documentation says:

> Resolves method arguments annotated with @RequestParam, arguments of
> type MultipartFile in conjunction with Spring's MultipartResolver
> abstraction, and arguments of type javax.servlet.http.Part in
> conjunction with Servlet 3.0 multipart requests. This resolver can
> also be created in default resolution mode in which simple types (int,
> long, etc.) not annotated with @RequestParam are also treated as
> request parameters with the parameter name derived from the argument
> name. If the method parameter type is Map, the name specified in the
> annotation is used to resolve the request parameter String value. The
> value is then converted to a Map via type conversion assuming a
> suitable Converter or PropertyEditor has been registered. Or if a
> request parameter name is not specified the
> RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver is used instead to provide
> access to all request parameters in the form of a map.
>
> A WebDataBinder is invoked to apply type conversion to resolved
> request header values that don't yet match the method parameter type.

So that is the reason why it works.